# como cargar un modal con datos traídos de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un CRUD, de los 3 mantenimientos principales el de update es el que mas me esta complicando la vida.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del index.php en donde esta dos modales uno para el registro y otro para la actualización.

```html
<?php  
include 'ajax/db_connection.php';
$consultaPreguntas = "SELECT * FROM oficina"; 
$resultadoOficina = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $consultaPreguntas);
$opcionesOficina = '<option value="0"> Elija una oficina</option>';
$filaOficina;
  while($filaOficina=mysqli_fetch_object($resultadoOficina) )
  {
    $opcionesOficina.='<option value=
    "'.$filaOficina->idoficina.'">'.$filaOficina->titulo.'</option>';

  }
date_default_timezone_set("America/El_Salvador");
//para la fecha actual
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP and MySQL CRUD Operations Demo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS File  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Content Section -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Practica</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Nuevo registro</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Records:</h3>

            <div class="records_content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Content Section -->
<!-- Bootstrap Modals -->
<!-- Modal - Add New Record/User -->
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo Registro</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="form-group has-feedback">                  
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label" for="nombre">Nombre completo</label>                 
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre completo" data-error="ingrese nombres valido" required>
                  </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>   

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Nivel del usuario</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="nivel" name="nivel" value="Referente" required/> Referente por oficina/area de gestion
                        </label>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="nivel" name="nivel" value="Administrador" required/> Administrador
                        </label>
                    </div>                  
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class=" col-lg-6 control-label">Seleccione la oficina:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                    </span>
                      <select id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-control" required="true">
                      <?php echo $opcionesOficina; ?>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Username</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="nombre de usuario" ata-error="ingrese nombres valido" required/>
                  </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>                      
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="clave" name="clave" placeholder="Password" ata-error="ingrese nombres valido" required>
                </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>               
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" id="idoficina" name="idoficina" <?php echo $filaOficina ?>

            </div><!--fin del body-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<!-- // Modal -->
<!-- Modal - Update User details -->
<div class="modal fade" id="update_user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">                  
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label" for="nombre">Nombre completo</label>                 
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="update_nombre" name="update_nombre" placeholder="nombre completo" data-error="ingrese nombres valido" required>
                  </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>   

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Nivel del usuario</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="update_nivel" name="update_nivel" value="Referente" required/> Referente por oficina/area de gestion
                        </label>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" id="update_nivel" name="update_nivel" value="Administrador" required/> Administrador
                        </label>
                    </div>                  
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class=" col-lg-6 control-label">Seleccione la oficina:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                    </span>
                      <select id="update_titulo" name="update_titulo" class="form-control" required="true">
                      <?php echo $opcionesOficina; ?>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Username</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="update_username" id="update_username" placeholder="nombre de usuario" ata-error="ingrese nombres valido" required/>
                  </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>                      
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="update_clave" name="update_clave" placeholder="Password" ata-error="ingrese nombres valido" required>
                </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>               
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" id="update_idoficina" name="update_idoficina" <?php echo $filaOficina ?>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()" >Save Changes</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="oculto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Modal -->

<!-- Jquery JS file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JS file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estas son las funciones ajax para realizar las operaciones.

```js
// Add Record
function addRecord() {
    // get values
    var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    var nivel = $("#nivel").val();
    var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var clave = $("#clave").val();

    // Add record
    $.post("ajax/addRecord.php", {
        nombre: nombre,
        nivel: nivel,
        titulo: titulo,
        username: username,
        clave: clave
    }, function (data, status) {
        // close the popup
        $("#add_new_record_modal").modal("hide");

        // read records again
        readRecords();

        // clear fields from the popup
        $("#nombre").val("");
        $("#nivel").val("");
        $("#titulo").val("");
        $("#username").val("");
        $("#clave").val("");
    });
}

// READ records
function readRecords() {
    $.get("ajax/readRecords.php", {}, function (data, status) {
        $(".records_content").html(data);
    });
}//esta funcion carga el contenido de la tabla


function DeleteUser(idregistro_user) {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure, do you really want to delete User?");
    if (conf == true) {
        $.post("ajax/deleteUser.php", {
                idregistro_user: idregistro_user
            },
            function (data, status) {
                // reload Users by using readRecords();
                readRecords();
            }
        );
    }
}

function GetUserDetails(idregistro_user) {
    // Add User idregistro_user to the hidregistro_userden field for furture usage
    $("#oculto").val(idregistro_user);
    $.post("ajax/readUserDetails.php", {
            idregistro_user: idregistro_user
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // PARSE json data
            var user = JSON.parse(data);
            // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields
            $("#update_nombre").val(user.nombre);
            $("#update_nivel").val(user.nivel);
            $("#update_titulo").val(user.titulo);
            $("#update_username").val(user.username);
            $("#update_clave").val(user.clave);
        }
    );
    // Open modal popup
    $("#update_user").modal("show");
}

function UpdateUserDetails() {
    // get values
    var nombre = $("#update_nombre").val();
    var nivel = $("#update_nivel").val();
    var titulo = $("#update_titulo").val();
    var username = $("#update_username").val();
    var clave = $("#update_clave").val();
    // get hidden field value
    var idregistro_user = $("#oculto").val();

    // Update the details by requesting to the server using ajax
    $.post("ajax/updateUserDetails.php", {
            idregistro_user: idregistro_user,
            nombre: nombre,
            nivel: nivel,
            titulo: titulo,
            username: username,
            clave: clave
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // hide modal popup
            $("#update_user").modal("hide");
            // reload Users by using readRecords();
            readRecords();
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // READ recods on page load
    readRecords(); // calling function
});
```

Pero de por medio se encuentra el codigo que realiza el select y en el que se encuentras dos botones el de actualizar y eliminar el de eliminar funciona correctamente, pero el de actualizar cuando lo presiono pues segun la consola del Fire Fox captura los datos, pero no me carga el modal para realizar la actualización.

```html
<?php
 // include Database connection file 
 include("db_connection.php");

 // Design initial table header 
 $data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
       <th>ID_User.</th>
       <th>ID_Oficina</th>
       <th>Nombre</th>
       <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Nivel</th>
       <th>Actualizar</th>
       <th>Eliminar</th>
      </tr>';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM registro_user";

 if (!$result = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }

    // if query results contains rows then featch those rows 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
     $number = 1;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
      $data .= '<tr>
    <td>'.$number.'</td>
    <td>'.$row['idregistro_user'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['idoficina'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['nombre'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['password'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['fecha_registro'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['nivel'].'</td>
    <td>
     <button onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['idregistro_user'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
    </td>
    <td>
     <button onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['idregistro_user'].')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </td>
      </tr>';
      $number++;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     // records now found 
     $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">Records not found!</td></tr>';
    }

    $data .= '</table>';

    echo $data;
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<?php
// include Database connection file
include("db_connection.php");

// check request
if(isset($_POST))
{
    // get values
    $idregistro_user = $_POST['idregistro_user'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $nivel = $_POST['nivel'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $clave = $_POST['password'];
    date_default_timezone_set("America/El_Salvador");
    //para la fecha actual
    $hoy = date('Y-m-d');

    // Updaste User details
    $query = "UPDATE registro_user 
    SET titulo = '$titulo', nombre = '$nombre', username='$username', password = '$clave', fecha_registro='$hoy', nivel = '$nivel',  
    WHERE idregistro_user = '$idregistro_user'";

    if (!$result = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $query)) {
            exit(mysqli_error());
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que te sale en las herramientas de desarrollador en la pestaña Respuesta cuando haces la llamada a `readUserDetails.php` Por otra parte un problema que veo es que en las llamadas Ajax no observas la posibilidad que haya un error en la llamada del Ajax. Es bueno que tengas opción de devolver un JSON en el php del Ajax el cual indique que ha habido un error. En tu caso posiblemente sea ese el problema, estarás devolviendo algo que no es JSON y por eso falla tu javascript.

Comment: puede ver abajo, lo que me pides, pero no se crees que tiene algo que ver los tipos de controles que intento llenar con la información de la base de datos'????

Comment: Abajo se ve la pestaña de Post de la llamada al Ajax. Necesitamos ver la pestaña Respuesta. ( Si te fijas aparece Cabeceras - Post - Respuesta - Cookies - Pila de llamadas, eso son pestañas ).